# How to use TitanCleanup in 1.0.0?

Tags: groovy, titan, gremlin

I'm working on a school project and we've been experimenting with some bulk loading scripts. However, I need a way to clear our titan database of all vertices, edges, and properties to start over. From what I can tell, TitanCleanup.clear() is the way to do it. But whenever I go through gremlin and close the graph, calling TitanCleanup.clear(graph) just results in a groovysh_evaluate error. We can't find any better documentation of using TitanCleanup other than the titan docs which just say what it does. Any examples or pointers to where to look would be much appreciated.

Edit: This is the whole thing I'm putting into gremlin, including the stack trace

```
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('./conf/titan-hbase.properties')
==>standardtitangraph[hbase:[hadoop-16.csse.rose-hulman.edu]]
gremlin> g.close()
==>null
gremlin> TitanCleanup.clear(g)
No such property: TitanCleanup for class: groovysh_evaluate
Display stack trace? [yN] y
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: TitanCleanup for class: groovysh_evaluate
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:304)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:69)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:119)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:94)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:82)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:144)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:303)
```

Comment: Can you post the `groovysh_evaluate` error and stack trace?

Comment: Edited the main post with everything I was putting into gremlin and the corresponding stack trace

Comment: I'd be curious to hear more about your graph project. Reach out to us on the [gremlin-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gremlin-users), [aureliusgraphs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/aureliusgraphs), or [janusgraph-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/janusgraph-users) mailing lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to import the `TitanCleanup` class before you use it:

```
gremlin> import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.util.TitanCleanup
```

After you close the graph (as you were already doing), you should be able to run `TitanCleanup.clear(g)` successfully.